Angular: When to use signal() vs model()?
When should we use signal() vs model() in Angular?
Angular says the following:

ModelSignal is a WritableSignal which means that its value can be changed from anywhere using the set and update methods. When a new value is assigned, the ModelSignal will emit to its output. This is different from InputSignal which is read-only and can only be changed through the template.

It seems like ModelSignal is the same as WriteableSignal, with the only difference being that it will emit change event whenever written to it? But doesn't WriteableSignal also emit change event when we use WriteableSignal.set() or WriteableSignal.update()?
Below I have added two examples. The first example makes use of signal(), whereas the second example uses model(). Both seem work. Which in my situation would be the most appropriate to use?
Example using signal():
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
  <input type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="quantity"/>

        {{quantity()}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  quantity = signal<number>(1);
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Example using model():
import { Component, model } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
  <input type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="quantity"/>

        {{quantity()}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  quantity = model<number>(1);
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


The answer is given in the angular docs.
Differences between model() and input()

Both input() and model() functions are ways to define signal-based inputs in Angular, but they differ in a few ways:

model() defines both an input and an output. The output's name is always the name of the input suffixed with Change to support two-way bindings. It will be up to the consumer of your directive to decide if they want to use just the input, just the output, or both.
ModelSignal is a WritableSignal which means that its value can be changed from anywhere using the set and update methods. When a new value is assigned, the ModelSignal will emit to its output. This is different from InputSignal which is read-only and can only be changed through the template.
Model inputs do not support input transforms while signal inputs do.


Its best to go through the working example below, which is loaded with comments, for you to better understand the differences and get a deep understanding signals!
I have tried my best to highlight my full understanding of signal through the below working examples, along with the above three mentioned points!
MAIN (PARENT)
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
  <!-- model has @Input and @Output like syntax in once, notice the suffix Change added to the model's name (here its "modelName") -->
  <!-- inputs are great for @Input and better because you can make them mandatory, they cannot be changed, as far as I know!
-->
    <app-child 
    [modelName]="name" 
    (modelNameChange)="updateModelName($event)"
    [inputNameWithTransformAlias]="inputNameWithTransform"
    [inputNameWithoutTransformAlias]="inputNameWithoutTransform"
    [inputNameButMandatoryAlias]="inputNameButMandatory"
    />
    <hr/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string = 'Angular';
  inputNameWithTransform: string = 'input';
  inputNameWithoutTransform: string = 'input';
  inputNameButMandatory: string = 'input but mandatory';

  updateModelName(event: string | undefined) {
    this.name = event || '';
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

CHILD (CHILD)
import { Component, input, model, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
  <h1>Model Explanation</h1>
  <input [(ngModel)]="modelName"/> <!-- use model when you have an ngModel, it works great with it -->
  <button (click)="getModel()">get model value</button>
  <button (click)="setModel()">set model value</button>
  <div>Model Name: {{modelName()}}</div>
  <hr/>
  <h1>Input Explanation</h1>
  <div>Input Name With Transform: {{inputNameWithTransform()}}</div>
  <div>Input Name Without Transform: {{inputNameWithoutTransform()}}</div>
  <button (click)="getInputs()">get inputs values</button>
  <button (click)="setInputs()">set inputs values</button>
  <h1>Signal Explanation</h1>
  <div>Signal Name: {{signalName()}}</div>
  <button (click)="getSignal()">get signal value</button>
  <button (click)="setSignal()">set signal value</button>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  modelName = model<string>('', { alias: 'modelName' }); // notice there is no transform
  inputNameWithTransform = input<string, string>('', {
    // notice there is transform when type is <string, string>
    alias: 'inputNameWithTransformAlias',
    transform: (value: string) => `transformed ${value}`,
  });
  inputNameWithoutTransform = input<string>('', {
    // notice there is no transform when type is <string>
    alias: 'inputNameWithoutTransformAlias',
  });
  inputNameButMandatory = input.required<string, string>({
    // no default value, but if not specified on parent will error out!
    // notice there is transform when type is <string, string>
    alias: 'inputNameButMandatoryAlias',
    transform: (value: string) => `transformed ${value}`,
  });
  signalName = signal<string>('signalName', {
    // can set an initial value
    // signal do not have alias or transform, good for local variable like functionality!
    equal: (a, b) => a === b, // we can write a function which tells us when the signal detects a change,
  });

  constructor() {}

  // model has both get and set methods
  setModel() {
    this.modelName.set('was set using button');
  }
  getModel() {
    alert(this.modelName());
  }

  // input has get but no set methods
  setInputs() {
    alert('check the commented code!');
    // uncomment to see the errors!
    // this.inputNameWithTransform.set('was set using button');
    // this.inputNameWithoutTransform.set('was set using button');
    // this.inputNameButMandatory.set('was set using button');
  }
  getInputs() {
    alert(`
    inputNameWithTransform: ${this.inputNameWithTransform()}
    inputNameWithoutTransform: ${this.inputNameWithoutTransform()}
    inputNameButMandatory: ${this.inputNameButMandatory()}
    `);
  }

  // signals has both get and set methods
  setSignal() {
    this.signalName.set('was set using button');
  }
  getSignal() {
    alert(this.signalName());
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

REFERENCES
Signals Angular Docs
Signal Inputs Angular Docs
Signals Model Inputs Angular Docs
